# Access Duplicates highlighting those with different value

Tags: ms-access-2016

I have a single table called SPARES
The table has 3 fields, Stock_No, Store_Id, Description
In the data set there are duplicate Stock_Nos and in some cases the descriptions vary
I make one query to extract the duplicate stock Nos then tried a 2nd query based on the first but don’t know how to extract records with duplicate Stock_Nos but with different descriptions
Can anyone help?
Can it be done in one query?

Comment: Please add some more detail - table definitions, the code you've tried so far, desired results and actual results

Comment: Hi John I made one query to find all duplicates stock Nos, a 2nd duplicate query to find where I had duplicate stock nos in the same store

Comment: Then got stuck how to extract duplicate Stock Nos that had different descriptions assigned